# C2DM - onMessage, interactivity with results I get

Tags: android, interactive, android-c2dm

I am successfully getting messages from C2DM service. Unfortunately I am not able to anyhow interact with them (set the string I get as a notification, or set it as a string in toast message,...). Is there any example how to do that?

SC:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("C2DM", "Message: arived");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        Log.d("DATA_ZE_SERVERU",extras.get("payload")+"");
        //how to interact with data?
    }
```

}

Thx

Nobody knows???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the string to a activity and let the activity show it. I did most of my c2dm like that.

Comment: Ok, but how to do that? Do you have any snippet? Because, what you are just saying, is that I make new activity, put extras to it and than display it...

Comment: Intent callIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
  callIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  callIntent.setAction(MainActivity.CALLBACK_ACTION);
  callIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.DATA,"data");
  context.startActivity(callIntent);